# How to create the corner that show in picture with css in webpage?

Tags: html, css, border, radius

How to create the curve that you see in picture with CSS and HTML?
Can I use CSS border radius or use other solution?

[image]

Comment: you can use border radius..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with two divs and psuedo elements :before and :after. Working code below

```css
.top-bar{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #55c3ff;
}

.curved-bottom{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #55c3ff;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.curved-bottom:before {
    height: 50px;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    left: -16%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
}

.curved-bottom:after {
    height: 50px;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    right: -16%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar"></div>
<div class="curved-bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main horizontal blue bar is a div, and the box sticking down is a separate div, you can use the pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` to create those inner radius.

See the following as an example:

```css
html,
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #5DC4FD;
 width: 100%;
 height: 160px;
}

.tab {
 position: relative;
 top: 130px;
 background-color: #5DC4FD;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 0  0 30px 30px;
}

.tab:before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 left: -50%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.tab:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 right: -50%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="tab">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use overlapping divs like this:

```css
#top {
    background: #00BFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
#container{
    display: flex;
}
#mid{
    background: #00BFFF;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
#left{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
#right{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

but I'd recommend using a background image with the desired shape